# Loop Datagridview rows and Insert to Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I need to loop through `Datagridview` rows and Insert each row in Oracle DB table. This should be done by checking if first cell is empty or not. Here is what I tried so far:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows    
     If row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then   
           'Do nothing    
     Else   
            Dim test = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            'MsgBox(test)

            Const SQL1 As String = "INSERT INTO MyTable2 (ID_Table2, ID_Table1, TEST)
                           VALUES(ID_Table2_seq.nextval,ID_Table1_seq.currval,: test)"

            cmd.CommandText = SQL1
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("test", test))

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()          
     End If
Next
```

I get error:

> External component has thrown an exception.

`cmd` is allready set and connected to OracleDB.

`ID_Table2_seq.nextval` and `ID_Table1_seq.currval` are sequences created in Oracle. And if I remove adding parameters and just showing `test` value in Msgbox it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For each loop was turned around, It holded wrong value first. I also had to add another "OracleCommand". This worked:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows    

   If row.Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then   

        Using cmd1 As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
            cmd1.Connection = con

             Dim SQL1 As String = "INSERT INTO MyTable2 (ID_Table2, ID_Table1, TEST)
                               VALUES(ID_Table2_seq.nextval,ID_Table1_seq.currval,: test)"
             cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("test", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString))
             cmd1.CommandText = SQL1
             cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() 

         End Using

   Else

   End If

 Next
```

Any explanation on why this happens ?